# Which algorithm does Java use for multiplication?

Tags: java, algorithm, math, multiplication, biginteger

The list of possible **algorithms for multiplication** is quite long:

- Schoolbook long multiplication
- Karatsuba algorithm
- 3-way Toom–Cook multiplication
- k-way Toom–Cook multiplication
- Mixed-level Toom–Cook
- Schönhage–Strassen algorithm
- Fürer's algorithm

Which one is used by Java by default and why? When does it switch to a *"better performance"* algorithm?

Comment: You mean like this? https://www.righto.com/2020/08/reverse-engineering-8086s.html

Comment: Can you please clarify whether you are talking about basic integer multiplication like `123 * 345`? Or if you are talking about multiplication with more complex objects like `BigInteger` which are not represented by a fixed amount of bytes? Depending on that your question might either be answered by _"whatever the underlying CPU uses"_, since regular integer multiplication is just _forwarded_ to the CPU and not implemented by the JVM itself.

Comment: actually I need the algorithm i.e. the software part.
```@OrangeDog```

Comment: well it is about medium sized numbers and big numbers.
```@Zabuzard```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Well ... the `*` operator will use whatever the hardware provides.  Java has no say in it.

But if you are talking about `BigInteger.multiply(BigInteger)`, the answer depends on the Java version.  For Java 11 it uses:

- naive "long multiplication" for small numbers,
- Karatsuba algorithm for medium sized number, and
- 3-way Toom–Cook multiplication for large numbers.

The thresholds are Karatsuba for numbers represented by 80 to 239 `int` values, an 3-way Toom-Cook for >= 240 `int` values.  The smaller of the numbers being multiplied controls the algorithm selection.

---

> Which one is used by Java by default and why?

Which ones?  See above.

Why?  Comments in the code imply that the thresholds were chosen empirically; i.e. someone did some systematic testing to determine which threshold values gave the best performance<sup>1</sup>.

You can find more details by reading the [source code](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/math/BigInteger.java#L1579)<sup>2</sup>.

---

<sup>1 - The current implementation `BigInteger` implementation hasn't changed significantly since 2013, so it is possible that it doesn't incorporate more recent research results.

2 - Note that this link is to the *latest* version on Github.</sup>

Comment: can you please send me a link so I can read more information about? ```@Zabuzard @Stephen```

Comment: See the source code link in my answer.   That is the only public information I'm aware of about how Java does this.